# Only the latest post shows up on post page?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks

disclaimer: this is my first foray into wordpress

I'm creating a custom theme and in the `single.php` file, i have the main loop, however if i navigate to different posts, all that shows up is the latest post. I could go to the different permalinks, but the only post that shows up is the latest one. How do I make it so that the correct post shows up?

I tried changing the permalinks and deleting and adding pages, but I get the same result.
Here is `single.php`

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

    <section class="main-section">
        <header>
            <h1 class="section-header"><?php the_category('/');?></h1>
            <ul class="section-nav">
                <?php
                    $cat = get_the_category()[0];
                    $categoryPosts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat->term_id));

                    foreach($categoryPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
                ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <h2 class="section-blurb"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <div class="info">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Everything works..but only for the latest post.

**Edit:**
I reinstalled wordpress fresh and made new pages, but the result is the same. I even stripped the code down to just

`<?php the_title(); ?>`

in the `single.php` file, but the result is the same. No matter which post you're supposed to be viewing, it only shows the latest post.

Comment: what do the contents of your `single.php` file look like? edit your question to add the code.

Comment: @Milo I added the code

Comment: so for each post you are also outputting posts from the same category above the post's content?

Comment: @Milo Yes, that's correct. As a sort of navigation because this is actually a website instead of a blog.

Comment: @PieterGoosen `setup_postdata` won't work unless you use `$post`

Comment: try adding a 'posts_per_page' parameter to your `get_posts()` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your structure here is wrong. I would completely remove your custom query from inside your loop and move it outside. Another option is to make use of other variable names in your custom query and making direct use of the [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects

As @Milo already explained, your custom query is most probably affecting the value of your `$post` global

### OPTION 1

Move the custom query outside your loop (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
<section class="main-section">

    <header>
        <h1 class="section-header"><?php the_category('/', '', get_queried_object_id() );?></h1>
        <ul class="section-nav">

        <?php
            $cat = get_the_category( get_queried_object_id() )[0];
            $categoryPosts = get_posts( array( 'category' => $cat->term_id ) );

            foreach($categoryPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
        ?>

               <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

               <?php unset( $post ); ?>

         <?php endforeach; ?>

       </ul>
    </header>
```

Then run your loop as normal. `the_post()` in your loop will reset your `$post` global to the main query

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

        <h2 class="section-blurb"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <div class="info">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

### OPTION 2

Use different variable names (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

    <section class="main-section">
        <header>
            <h1 class="section-header"><?php the_category('/');?></h1>
            <ul class="section-nav">
                <?php
                    $cat = get_the_category()[0];
                    $categoryPosts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat->term_id));

                    foreach($categoryPosts as $categoryPost):

                       $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $categoryPost->post_title ); ?>
                        <li>
                             <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                  <?php echo $title; ?>
                             </a>
                        </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php unset( $categoryPost ); ?>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <h2 class="section-blurb"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <div class="info">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: I tried both your advice, but it still doesn't seem to work. Please see my edit

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed

Comment: No, i disabled all the plug-ins

Comment: OK, so you have wordpress reinstalled, disabled all plugins. Have you switched to a bundled theme, what is the result

Comment: the twentyfifteen theme works fine.

Comment: So it is your theme. Do you have any custom query in your header, sidebar, a widget that is active on that page, maybe a related post function. Are you using `pre_get_posts` somewhere or even `query_posts` on your single post. Remove your header, sidebar and footer one by one and retest. Also remove all widgets one by one, and any custom function

Comment: I followed your advice and got to a conclusion. I actually was trying to do three loops inside one wordpress lifecycle. I had one in the header and two in the `single.php`.  
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. Glad you were able to solve your issue. Enjoy, and have a blast of a new year :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setup_postdata($post);`, that populates the global `$post` with the current post in your `$categoryPosts` result set.

After the `foreach` terminates and you try to output the regular post data with template tags:

```
<h2 class="section-blurb"><?php the_title();?></h2>
<div class="info">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Those template tags are getting their data from `$post`, which still contains whatever was the last post in your `$categoryPosts`.

To fix that, you need to reset the value of `$post` to what it was before you ran the secondary query, with [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata):

```
foreach($categoryPosts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
    // output post
endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata();

// now you can return to outputting the post in the main loop
the_title();
```

Comment: nope, added the code and it's still only showing the latest post. I removed the whole `setup_postdata()` function and it still did the same thing.

Comment: update your question to show your current code.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: when I copy and paste your code into a `single.php` template it works as expected. I see a list of the latest 10 posts in the same category above the selected single post. I see 10 because that's the value of *Blog pages show at most* under Settings > Reading.

Comment: Yeah, the category navigation parts work fine, but it seems to only work with that last post that was no matter what post you're supposed to be on. All the content is there, but if you go to see another post, you just keep getting the same one.

Comment: please see my edit. I added more information